# Functionality to save and restore database state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, backup

I would like to create a functionality in my program to save current database state and be able to restore it in future. I would also like to be able, if I go back to some state from, let's say 2 days ago, to return to a state from today. I was thinking about restoring a database from a transaction log (everytime I want to save the state I commit a mareked transaction (on some insignificant data)). Is it possible at all, using this solution to restore some earlier state and after that be able to restore a more recent state, or would I lost it after the restore (or they would disappear form transaction log)?

Comment: its called a full backup (plus Tlog backups)

Answer (score 5):

[Database snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190467.aspx) ?

Comment: unfortunately I use express version, forgot to mention that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think this is bad idea. You should look at CQRS + Event Sourcing solution.

- http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/2010/07/cqrs-event-store.html

Comment: That answer appears to have nothing to do with the question

Comment: Really? Did you read something about CQRS + Event Sourcing? This solution gives you possibility to create snapshots on business level and restore object state from any time back (not related to database engine).